# Why does git not spawn the GPG agent?

Tags: git, gnupg, sign

I'm always using signed commits when committing to my git repo. I'm using the ncurses gpg agent. The commit fails with the standard error

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

**Anyway** I have an empty file `dummy.txt` in my repo, and after I execute

```
gpg --clearsign dummy.txt
```

the ncurses agent pop up, asks for the password and unlocks the key for 5 minutes. Then all git commits, that I do in the next 5 minutes are successfully signed. That means the git configuration is correct. But maybe it has no permission to spawn ncurses?

Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: ncurses is only a symptom here - you'll have to identify which system and version, and probably open a bug-report if it's of interest to the developer.